# "systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service" slow on read-only filesystem

Tags: systemd, boot, embedded, readonly, headless

On a headless embedded computer (booting on a *read-only* filesystem), I see that `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` is rather slow, and prevents other services to start earlier (I checked with `systemctl list-dependencies myservice.service`).

**How to make it faster on a read-only filesystem?**

`journalctl -u systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` also confirms it takes nearly 4 seconds:

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2021-12-11 01:55:43 GMT, end at Sat 2021-12-11 01:58:03 GMT. --
Dec 11 01:55:**43** foo systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Dec 11 01:55:**47** foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: **rm_rf(/tmp): Read-only file system**
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: symlink(/etc/machine-id, /var/lib/dbus/machine-id) failed: Read-only file system
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: symlink(../proc/self/mounts, /etc/mtab) failed: Read-only file system
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: Failed to open directory 'coredump': No such file or directory
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: Failed to open directory 'private': No such file or directory
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: Failed to open directory 'private': No such file or directory
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: Failed to open directory 'private': No such file or directory
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: Failed to open directory '.X11-unix': No such file or directory
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: Failed to open directory '.ICE-unix': No such file or directory
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: Failed to open directory '.XIM-unix': No such file or directory
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: Failed to open directory '.font-unix': No such file or directory
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd-tmpfiles[149]: Failed to open directory '.Test-unix': No such file or directory
Dec 11 01:55:47 foo systemd[1]: Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
```

Here is the result of `systemd-analyze plot`:

[image]

Comment: It makes me wonder (idle speculation) if it uses some sort of state file to keep track of "tmpfiles" and their ages, and -- lacking that file, or having an old state file -- it is forced to re-crawl the filesystem(s).

Comment: @JeffSchaller This could be possible indeed, good idea!

Comment: Another possibility is that it's attempting to touch or write files and those are timing out / being retried, causing some time lost.  I started looking at [the source](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/b049b48c4b6e60c3cbec9d2884f90fd4e7013219/src/tmpfiles/tmpfiles.c) but can't see this all the way through right now.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Oh yes this could be the reason as well! Thanks! Is there something documented about read-only root filesystems? I think this is a fairly common use-case, so `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` should probably handle it somewhere?

Comment: Sure, happy to help move things towards an Answer! I haven't gotten far enough into systemd-tmpfiles to say one way or the other, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` is defined in `/usr/lib/systemd/...` I used the "masking" technique from the article ["Three levels of off"](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/three-levels-of-off):

> By symlinking a service file to /dev/null you tell systemd to never start the service in question and completely block its execution. Unit files stored in /etc/systemd/system override those from /lib/systemd/system that carry the same name. The former directory is administrator territory, the latter terroritory of your package manager. By installing your symlink in /etc/systemd/system/ntpd.service you hence make sure that systemd will never read the upstream shipped service file /lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service.

I did

```
ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
```

I'm still interested if there is a "more clever solution" to make `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service` work even on read-only systems, without waiting 4 seconds for nothing. Ideas welcome in comments or another answer!